# scrollView.setContentOffset doesn't work after scrollView.contentInset on iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, ios12

I have screen with scrollView and bottomContainerView with two textFields and two buttons. And I want to scrollView scroll to bottom when keyboard was shown. That is why I firstly set scrollView.contentOffset and then I am trying to make frame of forgetButton visible(to scroll all view to bottom). And in iOS 11.4 it works. But in iOS 12 doesn't.

```
private func adjustInsetForKeyboardShow(_ show: Bool, notification: Notification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo ?? [:]
    if let keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        let adjustmentHeight = (keyboardFrame.height + 24) * (show ? 1 : 0)
        scrollView.contentInset.bottom = adjustmentHeight
        scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom = adjustmentHeight

        // set offset
        let top = bottomContainerView.frame.minY + forgetButton.frame.minY
        let height = forgetButton.frame.height
        scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x: 0, y: top, width: 1, height: height), animated: true)

    }
}

@objc
private func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    adjustInsetForKeyboardShow(true, notification: notification)
}

@objc
private func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
    adjustInsetForKeyboardShow(false, notification: notification)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}
```

**iOS 11.4**

[image: iOS 11.4]

**iOS 12.0**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change this part:

```
let userInfo = notification.userInfo!
let keyboardFrame = info[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect
```

Alternatively: create a constraint with the bottom of the View, and when the keyboard is open add to the contraint the height dimension of the keyboard (keyboardFrame.height), and update the constraint with animations

```
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
  self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
 }
```

Regards

Comment: Your solution is the same. You just make type transformation in another way. But the problem was in scrollView, not in keyboardRect.